# Choosing btw Scrapy V1.8 and V2.0

Tags: scrapy

Hi I have wanted to learn Scrapy and use it to scrape dynamic data off of webpages, and use it in a website backend.

When I went to the official docs, I go to know that V.2.0 just came out.

Given that I'm new to scrappy, and plan to develop an autonomous hosted application, I was wondering whether I should choose v 1.8 over v 2.0 because bugs would've been worked out better and there'll be more tutorials etc. But on the other hand, I'll end up learning 2.0 anyway in the future, so maybe I should start with 2.0 itself.

So I have two questions:

- Are there any major changes from v1.8 to v.2.0 (I am aware that there are release notes that accompany each version, but the only thing that I can really understand is that Python 2 support was removed; everything else uses terminology that I don't understand.)
- I'd be grateful for your advice on which one I should opt for.

I have worked with Selenium & BeatifulSoup4 on 1 project before hand, which involved scraping stock price and relative strength index, and using that as a part of Flask backed web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the latest Scrapy release for a new project, unless you cannot for some reason.

There are no major changes in how Scrapy works between 1.8 and 2.0; upgrading from 1.8 to 2.0 should be as easy as upgrading from 1.7 to 1.8.